# ArcPy Insert Cursor giving RuntimeError: Error in InsertRow

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

When I run the code snippet below, to create a test table, add a field to it, and populate that field with a value in its first row, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.insertRow(row)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 230, in insertRow
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.InsertRow(*gp_fixargs(args)))
RuntimeError: Error in InsertRow
```

---

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\Projects\TestProject\TestProject.gdb"
arcpy.CreateTable_management(arcpy.env.workspace,"TestTable")
arcpy.AddField_management('TestTable',"ID","SHORT")
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor('TestTable',["ID"])
row=[50]
cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me more time than I would like to admit to find that this error is due to inadvertently using an `arcpy.InsertCursor()` when intending to use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor()`.

This code snippet will work as intended:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\Projects\TestProject\TestProject.gdb"
arcpy.CreateTable_management(arcpy.env.workspace,"TestTable")
arcpy.AddField_management('TestTable',"ID","SHORT")
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('TestTable',["ID"])
row=[50]
cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```